# Android - How to sort arrayList by date?

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to sort my `arrayList` by date. I stored the date on Firebase each time I receive a notification and is retrieved from there. I'm using `Collections.sort` but I don't know how to implement onto my codes as my date format starts with a number in a string format like "12 Jul 2017 at 12:00am".

I've seen some examples of this on stackoverflow but I don't know how to make it work in my case. I will post screenshots and my codes below.

The dates are not sorted.

[image]

**NotificationFragment.java**

```
public class NotificationFragment extends Fragment {
        prepareNotification1();
        sortDate();
        return v;
    }

       private void prepareNotification1() {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            String userID = user.getUid();

  mRef.child("customers").child(userID).child("Notification").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Notification menu = dataSnapshot.getValue(Notification.class);
                    notificationList.add(menu);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
 });
    }

    public void sortDate() {
        Collections.sort(notificationList, new Comparator<Notification>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Notification lhs, Notification rhs) {
                return lhs.getDate().compareTo(rhs.getDate());
            }
        });
        mAdapter = new NotificationAdapter(getContext(), notificationList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        String currentTime = df.format(cal.getTime());

        String notificationTime = currentDateTimeString + " at " + currentTime;

        Notification newNotification = new Notification(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"), notificationTime);
        mRef.child("customers").child(userID).child("Notification").push().setValue(newNotification);
}
```

**Notification.java**

```
public class Notification {
    private String message;
    private String date;


    public Notification(){
    }

    public Notification(String message, String date){
        this.message = message;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is getDate() returning String or Date foramt?

Comment: @UsmanRana String format. I stored it as a string in Firebase each time I receive a notification.

Comment: I don't know Firebase, but assuming it is even remotely similar to other databases it must have a date type.  Store your dates in this type.

Comment: please print the value of getDate in Logs and post here, there might be some issue in format

Comment: post your Notification.java

Comment: Further to @TimBiegeleisen comment, if it is similar to other databases then selecting with an `order by datefield` would be better

Comment: [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15462829/9312502) you must check it maybe help

Answer (score 11):

Do sorting after parsing the date.

```
Collections.sort(notificationList, new Comparator<Notification>() {
            DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy '@'hh:mm a");
            @Override
            public int compare(Notification lhs, Notification rhs) {
                try {
                    return f.parse(lhs.getDate()).compareTo(f.parse(rhs.getDate()));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                }
            }
        })
```

If your date is in some other format, write the **DateFormat** accordingly.

Comment: Don't know why this answer have any upvotes. Its working fine for me. Thanks Ritesh.

Answer (score 5):

Consider storing the date in `Notification` as a `long` (unix time) or a `Date` (`LocalDateTime` if you're using Java 8 support) and formatting it as a String only when displaying it to the UI.

Comment: Oh thanks, I think I get it. I store it as a string in my 'Notification'

Answer (score 2):

## Sort ArrayList by Date in Ascending and Descending order

In my answer I will use an `ArrayList` for debts named `debtsArrayList`. This answer will show how to sort an `ArrayList` with objects by `date` in both `ascending` and `descending` order.

## Sort comparator class

First create a `SortComparator` class to hold the functions to sort by date in `ascending` and `descending` order.

```
public class SortComparator {

    /**
     * Class to sort list by Date
     */
    public static class SortBy_Date {

        /**
         * Class to sort list by Date in ascending order
         */
        public static class Ascending implements Comparator<JB_Debts> {

            @Override
            public int compare(JB_Debts jbDebts1, JB_Debts jbDebts2) {

                // Create DateFormat
                DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(
                        DateFormat.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);

                // Catch Parse errors
                try {

                    // Parse dates
                    Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(jbDebts1.getDate());
                    Date date2 = dateFormat.parse(jbDebts2.getDate());

                    // Check if dates are null
                    if ((date1 != null) && (date2 != null)) {

                        // Ascending
                        return (date1.getTime() > date2.getTime() ? 1 : -1);

                    } else {

                        return 0; // Return 0 to leave it at current index
                    }
                } catch (Exception exception) {

                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }

                return 0;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Class to sort list by Date in descending order
         */
        public static class Descending implements Comparator<JB_Debts> {

            @Override
            public int compare(JB_Debts jbDebts1, JB_Debts jbDebts2) {

                // Create DateFormat
                DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(
                        DateFormat.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);

                // Catch Parse and NullPointerExceptions
                try {

                    // Parse dates
                    Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(jbDebts1.getDate());
                    Date date2 = dateFormat.parse(jbDebts2.getDate());

                    // Check if dates are null
                    if ((date1 != null) && (date2 != null)) {

                        // Descending
                        return (date1.getTime() > date2.getTime() ? -1 : 1);

                    } else {

                        return 0; // Return 0 to leave it at current index
                    }
                } catch (Exception exception) {

                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }

                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my example I am using an ArrayList with objects `ArrayList<JB_Debts>` where `JB_Debts` is my Java bean class with getter and setter methods.

```
    public class JB_Debts {

    private String date; // Our date string

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public JB_Debts2() {
    }

    /**
     * Function to get date
     */
    public String getDate() {

        return date;
    }

    /**
     * Function to set date
     *
     * @param date - Date
     */
    public void setDate(String date) {

        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

## Using the class with collections

We will then use this class with Java collections to sort our ArrayList<JB_Debts> with objects based on Date in ascending and descending order.

```
// Create ArrayList
ArrayList<JB_Debts> debtsArrayList = new ArrayList();

Collections.sort(debtsArrayList,
            new SortComparator.SortBy_Date.Ascending());

Collections.sort(debtsArrayList,
            new SortComparator.SortBy_Date.Descending());
```

**Note**

Please note that I stored the date in my ArrayList as a string. To sort them, I parsed the string to date as below:

```
// Create DateFormat with Locale
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(
                DateFormat.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);

// Create DateFormat without Locale
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(
                DateFormat.FULL);
```

You can replace the `DateFormat.FULL` with a date format of your choice e.g. `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"` which will then look as below:

```
// Create DateFormat with Locale
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);

// Create DateFormat without Locale
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You can simply parse the date-time strings into `LocalDateTime` and perform a natural sorting.

**Using `Stream`:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM u 'at' h:m a", Locale.UK);
        
        Stream.of(
                    "10 Jul 2017 at 10:59 pm",
                    "10 Jul 2017 at 10:59 pm",
                    "11 Jul 2017 at 11:15 pm",
                    "9 Jul 2017 at 11:15 pm"
                )
                .map(s -> LocalDateTime.parse(s, dtf))
                .sorted()
                .forEach(dt -> System.out.println(dtf.format(dt)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
9 Jul 2017 at 11:15 pm
10 Jul 2017 at 10:59 pm
10 Jul 2017 at 10:59 pm
11 Jul 2017 at 11:15 pm
```

**Non-`Stream` solution:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM u 'at' h:m a", Locale.UK);
        List<LocalDateTime> listLdt = new ArrayList<>();
        
        List<String> listDtStr = 
                Arrays.asList(
                                "10 Jul 2017 at 10:59 pm",
                                "10 Jul 2017 at 10:59 pm",
                                "11 Jul 2017 at 11:15 pm",
                                "9 Jul 2017 at 11:15 pm"
                            );
        
        // Add the strings, parsed into LocalDateTime, to listLdt
        for(String s: listDtStr) {
            listLdt.add(LocalDateTime.parse(s, dtf));
        }
        
        // Sort listLdt
        Collections.sort(listLdt);
        
        // Display
        for(LocalDateTime ldt: listLdt) {
            System.out.println(ldt.format(dtf));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
9 Jul 2017 at 11:15 pm
10 Jul 2017 at 10:59 pm
10 Jul 2017 at 10:59 pm
11 Jul 2017 at 11:15 pm
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Using legacy date-time API:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM u 'at' h:m a", Locale.UK);
        List<Date> listDate = new ArrayList<>();
        
        List<String> listDtStr = 
                Arrays.asList(
                                "10 Jul 2017 at 10:59 pm",
                                "10 Jul 2017 at 10:59 pm",
                                "11 Jul 2017 at 11:15 pm",
                                "9 Jul 2017 at 11:15 pm"
                            );
        
        // Add the strings, parsed into LocalDateTime, to listDate
        for(String s: listDtStr) {
            listDate.add(sdf.parse(s));
        }
        
        // Sort listDate
        Collections.sort(listDate);
        
        // Display
        for(Date date: listDate) {
            System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
9 Jul 4 at 11:15 pm
10 Jul 5 at 10:59 pm
10 Jul 5 at 10:59 pm
11 Jul 6 at 11:15 pm
```

**Note:** The `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> .

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, Notification.getDate() returns String value. So, use

```
public static Date toDate(String value) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy 'at' HH:mm'am'", Locale.ENGLISH);
    return format.parse(value);
}
```

this method to det Date from your String. Just get two dates and use Date.compareTo method.

```
date1 = toDate(lhs.getDate());
date2 = toDate(rhs.getDate());
date1.compareTo(date2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting date like following in Notification model.

`String notificationTime = currentDateTimeString + " at " + currentTime;`

you can save time as **System.currentTimeinMillis();** and while displaying then parse it to Date as following

```
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
f.parse(timeStamp);
```